# Unicode routes.rb and Passenger vs. Mongrel/WEBrick Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My (Rails 3) routes.rb has the following entry:

```
resources :articles, :path => "記事"
```

This works in my production environment, as passenger unescapes the 
path from /%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B to /記事.

However, in my development environment, I'm using Mongrel, which does 
not unescape the path, so it does not work unless I change my routes 
to

```
resources :articles, :path => Rack::Utils.escape("記事")
```

I'm trying to figure out which component has the bug.  Any 
suggestions?

Comment: I have opened this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [passenger issue](http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=404).

To work around it, you need to use the following:

```
match "記事" => "articles#index"
match "記事/:id" => "articles#show"
resources :articles, :path => Rack::Utils.escape("記事")
```

This will ensure articles_path will generate the escaped routes, while still responding to the unescaped passenger ones.

Answer (score 0):

I myself use passenger for development too. Since passenger 3 there is a [Passenger Standalone](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html). It works very well for me.

```
cd /path/to/your/railsproject
passenger start
```